# Why did Kakashi not kill Hidan?

Tags: naruto

A few episodes after the battle with Hidan and Asuma... :'(. Shikamaru, Ino, Choji and Kakashi set out to find Hidan and Kakuzu. When they find them Shikamaru uses his shadow jutsu to "paralyze" the enemies. So far they can only see just Shikamaru. Why doesn't Kakashi use his new sharingan to completely obliterate hidan while he was frozen?

Please no spoilers as I am only in mid season 2.

Comment: What new Sharingan?

Comment: The Sharingan Kakashi used on Deidara that tore off his arm.

Comment: that's not really a "new" Sharingan. It's his Mangekyou Sharingan, Kamui, that he has pretty much had for a long time.

Comment: "new" to the show. First time you see it is when he uses it on Deidara.

Comment: I guess you can call it "new" for that reason, but in Naruto (the original) when Kakashi is fighting with Itachi, it was mentioned the he had one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**THAT IS STRATEGY.** When you don't even know a single thing about the enemy, would you go face to face directly? Well, in *Shikamaru's* case, there must be a person to be the bait, and once they make sure that the enemies are completely immobilized, the plan begins. Unfortunately, *Kakuzu* freed himself, so the plan failed.

**Why did *Ino* did not use the *Mind Body Switch Technique* on *Kakuzu*?**
**There are several reasons why *Ino* decided not to use it.**
**1.** If the opponent's will is strong enough, they can force the user to leave their body. Apparently the stronger one has the stronger will.
**2.** If the user's chakra level is low, the technique will be harder to maintain.
**3.** If any physical injury is inflicted on the victim's body while the mind link is active, it would cause the user's body to also receive those same injuries. This is a good chance for *Hidan* to kill her by piercing through one of *Kakuzu's* hearts, and *Kakuzu* will still be fine since he has multiple hearts. That is not a good idea to eliminate the target.

**Why didn't *Choji*, *Ino* and *Shikamaru* apply *Formation Ino–Shika–Chō* in the battle to distract *Kakuzu* while *Kakashi* was aiming at *Hidan* with his *Mangekyō Sharingan*?**
**1.** *Kakashi* initially having trouble to aim at his target with *Kamui* properly, he struggled to hit his target. Recall the episode when *Kakashi* is using *Kamui* on *Deidara*. *Hidan* is shown to be very skilled in melee combat, meaning he could run and jump to dodge *Kakashi's* aim.
**2.** It requires some amount of preparation time and has a huge drain on his chakra each time it is performed. If he missed, a huge portion of his chakra is wasted.
**3.** *Kakashi* hasn't completely mastered *Kamui* yet, so at the time transporting an arm was his limit. Don't forget that *Hidan* is an immortal bastard, decapitation only makes him immobilize. Even though *Kakashi* was capable to aim at *Hidan's* head accurately, *Kakuzu* could reveal his 4 masks with different nature affinity to disturb *Kakashi*.

Comment: Sure Kakuzu freed himself. Why did Ino not mind transfer to Kakuzu or even Choji and Ino battle him to distract while Kakashi used his sharingan. I get the whole **STRATEGY** thing but it could have been better.

Comment: @IE5Master See the edited answer.

Comment: +1 for immortal bastard. Thank you for your time, your answer was very informative.